# Remove datetime and time separator in date select with simple form rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, simple-form, separator

How I can remove datetime separator and time separator in date select create by gem called simple_form ?

I think I must override `initialize` method that simple_form use to create date select or pass hash options in input of my form. But it doesn't work.

I try something like this :

```
f.input :as => :date, options:{:date_separator => '', :time_separator => ''}
```

Thanks to help me

Answer (score 3):

You have to make this change to make it work:

```
f.input :your_attribute, as: :date, date_separator: '', time_separator: ''
# or
f.input :your_attribute, as: :date, date_separator: '<span>:</span>'
```

These 2 should work.

Answer (score 0):

You cant make it with simple_form only.

I recommend to process in controller.

```
protected

def process_business_hour(params)
    params[:business_hour] = "#{params[:"business_hour(4i)"].to_i}:#{params[:"business_hour(5i)"].to_i}"
    return params
end
```

Its really mess job, but if any other great method(only using simple_form), please let me know.

---

updated.

```
<%= f.date_select 'business_hour_mon_start', {minute_step: 5}, class: "timeselect timeselect_mon", onChange: "javascript:selectBusinessHour(this.value)" %>~
<%= f.time_select 'business_hour_mon_end', {minute_step: 5, ignore_date: :true}, class: "timeselect timeselect_mon", onChange: "javascript:selectBusinessHour(this.value)" %>
```

this method can..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Z0ur.png

check above image..

if is not enough, you can break apart like this.

```
<select id="parkinglot_business_hour_mon_start_1i" name="parkinglot[business_hour_mon_start(1i)]" onchange="javascript:selectBusinessHour(this.value)">
```

see **(1i)**

Comment: I think your don't understand what I should. I want to remove separator in form view only. The separator between hour select  and minute select for example.

Answer (score 0):

Upload another answer because I dont hove 10 or more reputation.

so I cant add image or more than two links..

---

and my last recommendation is mixing jQuery datepicker, not simple_form only.

http://oi58.tinypic.com/2d1mps2.jpg

check above image..

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

jQuery datepicker is well documented and easy to implement.

```
<input type="text" id="date_start" class="form-control" value="<%= 1.month.ago.to_date %>">

<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#date_start" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    defaultDate: "-1w -1d",
    changeMonth: true,
    maxDate: "-1",
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
      $( "#date_start" ).datepicker( "option", selectedDate );
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

sorry for this answer is not a direct solution.

customizing simple_form is always very annoying jog.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fix not ideal but works:

```
<script>
    var el = $("#mydiv");
    el.html(el.html().replace("—", ""));
    el.html(el.html().replace(":", ""));
</script>
```