# How to remove datetime separator in simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, haml, simple-form

I have simple_form input which takes input of datetime.

```
= f.input :input, as: :datetime, start_year: DateTime.now.year, label: false, selected: DateTime.now
```

That code is working, but there's separator between date and time. The format is looks like this.

```
"%d %B %Y-%H:%M"
```

What could I do so the format will be like this?

```
"%d %B %Y %H:%M"
```

I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217759/remove-datetime-and-time-separator-in-date-select-with-simple-form-rails), but there's nothing changed.

Code using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217759/remove-datetime-and-time-separator-in-date-select-with-simple-form-rails) method:

```
= f.input :input, as: :datetime, date_separator: '', time_separator: '', start_year: DateTime.now.year, label: false, selected: DateTime.now
```

Answer (score 0):

Magic option: `datetime_separator: ""`